# replace variable name in formula with Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, regex

In c#, I want use a regular expression to replace each variable @A with a number withouth replacing other similar variables like @AB

```
string input = "3*@A+3*@AB/@A";
string value = "5";
string pattern = "@A"; //<- this doesn't work
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, value);
// espected result = "3*5+3*@AB/5"
```

any good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
string pattern = @"@A\b";
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%40A%5Cb&i=3*%40A%2B3*%40AB%2F%40A&r=5) (*Context* tab)

Note the `@` before the string literal: I am using a verbatim string literal to declare the regex pattern so that I do not have to escape the `\`. Otherwise, it would look like `string pattern = "@A\\b";`.

Comment: Just a note: `\b` will fail a match if a letter or digit or underscore follow the `@A`. If you need to let digits and underscore after (if you want to replace `@A` in `@A6`) you can use `@A(?!\p{L})` regex.